# Using the integral mean value theorem for a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

Suppose $|u(t)| \to 0$ and $|u|$ is integrable. Then I want to prove
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_0^t e^{-t + s}|u(s)| ds = 0.
$$
For all $t > 0$ integral MVT gives for some $c \in (0,t)$
$$
e^{-t + c} \int_0^t |u(s)| ds.
$$

I'm worried though about the $c$ as $t \to \infty$; what is happening to $e^{-t + c}$ as $t \to \infty$ since $c \in (0,t)$? Could someone help me understand if this is the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_0^{t/2} e^{-t + s}|u(s)|\,\text{d}s\leq e^{-t/2}\int_0^{t/2} |u(s)| \,\text{d}s\to0$.

Also, $\displaystyle\int_{t/2}^t e^{-t + s}|u(s)|\,\text{d}s\leq e^0 \int_{t/2}^t |u(s)|\,\text{d}s\to0$.